# Docbook Webhelp

Tags: docbook

I have been using Docbook 5 and used webhelp to generate the 2 pane output. I would like to use  different theme instead of redmond. Could anyone suggest a way this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

If you customize the webhelp-common.xsl template, you can completely change the JavaScript that is imported by the webhelp HTML files. Here's the template, and some of the lines that import the Jquery JavaScript:

https://github.com/docbook/xslt10-stylesheets/blob/master/xsl/webhelp/xsl/webhelp-common.xsl#L159

Webhelp includes the Jquery that it imports in its templates directory:

https://github.com/docbook/xslt10-stylesheets/tree/master/xsl/webhelp/template/common/jquery

The last time I customized DocBook webhelp, I asked a web developer to give me an HTML page design and I customized webhelp-common.xsl to generate that HTML structure. I added and removed files from the templates directory to include the JavaScript and CSS that we wanted to use. I didn't find that to be too hard, but I'm fairly comfortable with XSLT.

I don't know enough about Jquery and themes to help with switching to a different theme. But if you are, you could try adjusting the theme included in the templates/common/jquery directory and making corresponding adjustments in the  imports in webhelp-common.xsl.

Good luck!

Comment: While this links may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Your answer can become invalid if the linked page changes